# How does this proof of Theorem 1 in Spivak's Calculus work?

Tags: notation, proof-explanation, absolute-value

Hello I just started Spivak's Calculus and I've come across something I don't really understand. What is trying to be proved is
$$ 
|a+b|\leq|a|+|b|\,.
$$
The proof is based on the observation that $|a|=\sqrt{a^2}$. So:
$$
\begin{align*}
(|a+b|)^2 = (a+b)^2 &= a^2+2ab+b^2 \\
&\leq a^2+2|a|\times|b|+b^2 \\
&= |a^2|+2|a|\times|b|+|b^2| \\
&= (|a|+|b|)^2 \\
\end{align*}
$$
Now what I don't understand is the change in relationship from line 1 to 2 ($= to \leq$) and from line 2 to 3 ($\leq to =$).

I attach the page because it's clearer there (I highlighted the proof in yellow). [*Actual proof from the book*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCk3N.png)

Comment: They used there that $x\leq |x|$ for all $x$, that $|xy|=|x||y|$ and that $|2|=2$. They used the first one for the case $x=2ab$. So, $2ab\leq |2ab|=2|a||b|$. Adding $a^2+b^2$ to both sides of this inequality gives the inequality that they wrote in that line.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Thank you for a first nicely posed question! +1 from me!

Comment: The proof is too complicated.  Adding $-|a| \le a \le |a|$ and $-|b| \le b \le |b|$ will do.

Comment: I don't think the proof is complicated at all. While that proof is shorter, it is more 'difficult' to find. I think Spivak asks for an alternative proof in the exercises though, so he is certainly aware.

Comment: So the change in signs from line 2 to 3 just means that the expression in line 3 equals the expression in line 2? Otherwise I still don't understand that change

Comment: Yes, the lines are read left to right and top to bottom. So the symbol $\leq$ on line 2 relates the last expression of line 1 to the next expression on line 2. Similarly, the symbol $=$ on line 3 relates the last expression of line 2 to the next expression on line 3.

Comment: That's exactly what was bothering me because I thought the expression on line 3 related to the expression on the left not to the one on line 2. Thank you!

Comment: I wasn't sure that was the problem, hence the comment. Let me write up an answer.

Comment: This proof does not use $|a|=\sqrt{a^2}$. You have $x^2\leq y^2$ and need to conclude from that that $x\leq y$. This is just true because squaring is an increasing function. "Taking the square root on both sides" doesn't magically get you out of having to use that fact, since that only works because the square root is an increasing function (which itself is only true because squaring is increasing).

Comment: I studied from Spivak over 25 years ago, and I remember being confused about this exact same notation (a long string of $=$/$\leq$/$<$ relations).  Servaes's explanation is spot on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The lines are read left to right and top to bottom. So the symbol ≤ on line 2 relates the last expression of line 1 to the next expression on line 2. Similarly, the symbol = on line 3 relates the last expression of line 2 to the next expression on line 3. The same thing could be written in one line as follows:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(|a+b|^2) = (a+b)^2 &= a^2+2ab+b^2
\leq a^2+2|a|\times|b|+b^2
= |a^2|+2|a|\times|b|+|b^2|
= (|a|+|b|)^2,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
but it is easier on the eyes to write each new expression on a new line.

Comment: It's particularly easier to read the multi-line version in MSE, as you don't have to try to separate out the far right of the expression from the "Hot Network Questions" it overlies.

Answer (score 6):

For any number $x \in \mathbb{R}: x \leq |x|$

Hence, $ab \leq |ab| = |a||b| \implies 2ab \leq 2|a||b| \implies a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \leq a^2 + 2 |a||b| + b ^2$

Answer (score 1):

$$a^2+2ab+b^2 
\leq a^2+2|a|\times|b|+b^2 $$ because $$ab \le |a||b|$$

Also $$a^2+2|a|\times|b|+b^2 = |a^2|+2|a|\times|b|+|b^2| $$

because $a^2 = |a|^2 $ and $b^2 = |b|^2 $